# Flash and Chrome Browser under Linux is not working properly anymore

Tags: linux, google-chrome

After a series of updates, my chrome browser will not display flash content properly anymore.

For example, if I go to speedtest.net I can see the speedtest applet but it's flickering funny colours and not loading correctly.

Other flash websites don't load at all.

Originally, I installed flash using the process described here.

http://maketecheasier.com/enable-flash-support-in-google-chrome-in-ubuntu/2009/08/19

I tried reinstalling everything but the result is the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself. One thing I didn't mention is that I'm on a 64bit version of linux.

I think this is the issue.

Solution for Chromium in Ubuntu or Kubuntu linux, uninstall the package flashplugin-installer
i.e. in a terminal window

```
sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-installer
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then run

```
sudo mkdir /opt/google/chrome/plugins
```

Next, Open this link: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplayer10/square/

Download the 64bit version of adobe flash player `square`.

Copy the enclosed libflashplayer.so to `/opt/google/chrome/plugins`

Restart chrome and it should be all go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Purge (completely remove) `flashplugin-nonfree` and then simply reinstall the same.

This downloads a new version of Flash player completely with updates etc automatically. No reboot needed.